# Angular2 SliderShow

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to build slider in angular2, but i have a lot of trouble with it. Ok, let's go to main problem. Why is this function getting me this error

**"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"**

This is my code ( i have tried a lot of things with ViewChild etc, now stuck at this problem ).

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, ViewChild } 

from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'slider',
    template: `
        <div class="slider-container">
            <header>
                <div class="slider-information">
                    <span class="slider-information--title" id="slidername">Acer C720-2103 Chromebook</span>
                    <span class="slider-information--category">
                        Category: <span id="slidercategory">Laptops</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="slider-information--learnmore">
                        More about <span id="sliderinfoname">Acer C720-2103 Chromebook</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-image">
                    <img id="sliderimage" src="../../../images/slider/laptop-slider.jpg" alt="Laptop">
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        :host{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    `]
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
    sliderCount: number = 0;
    images: any[];
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.images = this.createImages();
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.slider();
    }
    slider(): void{
        var slidername = document.getElementById('slidername');
        var sliderimage = document.getElementById('sliderimage');
        var sliderinfoname = document.getElementById('sliderinfoname');
        var slidercategory = document.getElementById('slidercategory');
        if(this.sliderCount > this.images.length - 1){
            this.sliderCount = 0;
        }
        slidername.innerHTML = this.images[this.sliderCount].name;
        sliderimage.setAttribute('src', this.images[this.sliderCount].url);
        sliderinfoname.innerHTML = this.images[this.sliderCount].name;
        slidercategory.innerHTML = this.images[this.sliderCount].category;
        this.sliderCount += 1;
        debugger;
        setTimeout(this.slider(), 2000);
    }
    createImages(): any[]{
        var newImages: any[];
        newImages = [
            { url: "../../../images/slider/laptop-slider.jpg", category: "Laptop" , name: "Acer C720-2103 Chromebook" },
            { url: "../../../images/slider/mobilephone-slider.jpg", category: "Phone", name: "Samsung Edge S6" }
        ]
        return newImages;
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I changed this
`setTimeout(this.slider(), 2000);` to `setTimeout(this.slider, 2000);`. It works only in first iternation. In second i am getting **"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"**

Comment: Keep your question focused on your error message; What kind of debugging have you done to find out why your stack is overflowing? "is my solution good" is not a good question for Stack Overflow because it's too broad and posts should be about one single question so they are useful to others.

Comment: I was debbugging to find out if text and src were changed ( yes it is, but only on debug mode ).

Comment: Have found the solution, but it made other bug :/ ( update )

Comment: I recommend you to check the angular 2 docs to see how to make this  simpler: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you were calling

`this.slider()` from within `this.slider()` because you were calling it instead of passing a reference to `this.slider`, that was causing a stack overflow.

Now you are passing a reference that doesn't have `this` correctly bound. Change it to

```
setTimeout(() => this.slider(), 2000);
```

That will run `this.slider()` after 2 secs with `this` correctly set. See [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

If you are calling `document.getElementById()`, you are not doing things as Angular would have you. That data you are digging out of the DOM should be passed to your component instead of tightly coupling your component to the environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Changed this ugly getElementById :)